# Non-integral underlying type for enum

Tags: objective-c, c, clang

I'm working on integrating objective-git into my project, but when I include their headers in my sources, I get these errors on several of their enum declarations:

> `objective-git/Classes/GTRepository.h:57:16: Non-integral type 'git_reset_t' is an invalid underlying type`

Here's the code in question:

```
typedef enum : git_reset_t {
    GTRepositoryResetTypeSoft = GIT_RESET_SOFT,
    GTRepositoryResetTypeMixed = GIT_RESET_MIXED,
    GTRepositoryResetTypeHard = GIT_RESET_HARD
} GTRepositoryResetType;
```

I changed `git_reset_t` to `NSUInteger` (typedef'd to unsigned long), and that got it to compile, but of course I'd rather not have to change the library files.

Objective-git compiles just fine in its own project, and I can't find any significant difference in the compiler settings between that project and mine. What could I be missing?

This is with Xcode 4.5, compiling with Apple llvm 4.1.

**Update:** The clue I missed was that the error only happened on a .mm file, and .m files were fine, so somehow the underlying enum type doesn't work in C++ (even if I enable C++11). As a workaround I put a fake minimal @interface declaration for the one objective-git class I use in that file so I don't have to include the headers, but I'd still like to find a cleaner solution.

Comment: Note that this relies on a Clang + ObjC specific extension: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#enumerations-with-a-fixed-underlying-type

Answer (score 1):

Google turns up [this file](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ALEXBIO/Git-Raw-0.20/xs/libgit2/include/git2/reset.h) containing this:

```
typedef enum {
    GIT_RESET_SOFT  = 1, /** Move the head to the given commit */
    GIT_RESET_MIXED = 2, /** SOFT plus reset index to the commit */
    GIT_RESET_HARD  = 3, /** MIXED plus changes in working tree discarded */
} git_reset_t;
```

This is an old-style enumeration with `int` being the underlying type. But it's not an `int`, it's a distinct type. And it's not integral and it can't be an underlying type for a new-style enumeration.

The fix is to use `typedef enum : int` or if you can use C++ and want to be extra expository,

```
typedef enum : std::underlying_type< git_reset_t >::type
```

I haven't tried, but you could also try this in ObjC without C++:

```
typedef enum : __underlying_type( git_reset_t )
```

Comment: But given that it compiles without errors in the objective-git project, there must be a non-code solution.

Comment: @Uncommon Are you sure they're using the exact same compiler version? The behavior of the extension might have changed. These things can have poor test coverage and it's likely the ObjC extension will evolve to be the same as the C++ standard feature.

Comment: Yes, I made sure I'm using the same compiler version as the objective-git project (Apple llvm 4.1).

Comment: @Uncommon Did you also clean both projects to make sure the appropriate compiler is actually processing all the source?

Comment: I'm pretty sure changing compilers forced a recompile on everything, but I cleaned and rebuilt just now for good measure. No change.

Comment: I tried adding a check for `__has_feature(objc_fixed_enum)` (from the clang doc you linked to), and it returns true for both my project and theirs.

Comment: Now I'm getting somewhere: the only file I'm getting this error on is a .mm file. If I set it to compile as plain Objective-C, the error goes away (but of course plenty of others pop up instead). `__has_feature(objc_fixed_enum)` still returns true either way.